# Generating a 30-32-bit PRP

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation, performance

I want to generate a small 30 or 32 bit PRP. I am going to use that PRP in an open web service and anyone will be able to get any number of plaintext-cyphertext pairs.

I've found an algorithm called [FastPRP](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/254) and the problem statement fits my requirements perfectly. However the performance seems quite low for 30-32 bit range.
I need a high-performant point evaluations for both PRP and an inverse PRP.

Are there any 32-bit PRP algorithms (less secure probably) that allow a faster point evaluations?

Comment: In the recent past I experimented with AES modified to remove the shiftrows operation, and a custom key schedule, that turned it into a 4-way parallel block cipher with hardware acceleration

Comment: Related: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/low-complexity-implementation-of-a-small-blocksize-cipher-64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a 32 bit PRP, might I suggest the [Speck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher)) cipher?  It isn't greatly secure (with a 32 bit block size, the only option is a 64 bit key, which isn't great), however it's *extremely* fast.

Comment: Thank you. I will use Speck for alfa testing because it's quite fast and simple. 48-bit version is also a nice option in case i need a bigger domain.